# Loop Records Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have five Stops

--------A-------------B------------C------------D------------E

I have Three columns in original table [Trip], I want to code the direction base on the logic

If my car goes from A to E, or any stops for that direction(B-D,C-E),the direction is South

If my car goes from E to A,or any stops for that direction(E-C,D-A),the direction is North

```
Trip    CarID   Stops
1      1000      A      
1      1000      B     
1      1000      C     
2      1001      C     
2      1001      D     
2      1001      E     
3      1002      D     
3      1002      C      
3      1002      B
```

I want the Result below:

```
Trip    CarID   Stops   Direction
1      1000      A      South
1      1000      B      South
1      1000      C      South
2      1001      C      South
2      1001      D      South
2      1001      E      South
3      1002      D      North
3      1002      C      North
3      1002      B      North
```

Anyone knows how to code this in access vba or query? The real table has more than 5 stops.

Comment: Is there any column in the original Trip table to tell you the definite order of those trips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will give some ideas

```
 Private Sub Command0_Click()
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim PreviousStop As String
 Dim Direction As String
 Dim PreviousDirection As String
 Dim rstCounter As Integer
 Dim currentCar As String
 Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Trip")
 With rst
    rstCounter = rst.RecordCount
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        If rstCounter = 1 Then
            Direction = calculatedDirection(PreviousStop, .Fields("Stops"))
            .Edit
            .Fields("Direction") = Direction
            .Update
            Exit Do
        Else
            PreviousStop = .Fields("Stops")
            currentCar = .Fields("CarID")
            .MoveNext
            If currentCar <> .Fields("CarID") Then
                PreviousDirection = ""
            Else
                If Len(PreviousDirection) > 0 Then
                    Direction = PreviousDirection
                Else
                    Direction = calculatedDirection(PreviousStop,     .Fields("Stops"))
                    PreviousDirection = Direction
                End If
            End If
            .MovePrevious
            If Len(Direction) > 0 Then
                .Edit
                .Fields("Direction") = Direction
                .Update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        End If
        rstCounter = rstCounter - 1
      Loop
  End With
End Sub  

Private Function calculatedDirection(PreviousStop As String, CurrentStop As String) As String
If PreviousStop > CurrentStop Then
            calculatedDirection = "North"
        Else
            calculatedDirection = "South"
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hey John your code is great! It works well but the only flaw is that the stops in real table are random letters that defines by human, so the condition of (PreviousStop > CurrentStop)  is not applicable.

Comment: For example: George Bush - Occur - CSH - LIVERPOOL - KINGGARD, they are all random names and the routes are defined by people. Is there any thing you can think of if I know the names and rules of the route(I know the sequence by names) ?  Thanks John

Comment: You could use a table that you could store all your stops and furthermore add a "weight"    like Bush --> weight 10, CSH -->Weight 15...etc. I am under the impression given the example you provided that you could use Latitude and Longitude to calculate your stops....

Comment: yeah you are right, I can always sign them numeric value. Thanks !